# can we show the records like date wise in json array in php?

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I had written like :

```
$qry2 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ( SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE id = m.meta_value ) AS image_url,date(p.post_date) as post_date,post_title as image_title FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta m WHERE p.post_type = 'image' AND p.post_status = 'publish' AND p.id = m.post_id AND p.post_title != 'Auto Draft' AND m.meta_key = '_thumbnail_id' order by p.post_date desc");


    foreach($qry2 as $thumb_url){

            $res_arr_value[$thumb_url->post_date][] = $thumb_url;
                }
        //  }

$msg= array('msg'=>'photo exist','status'=>'success','data'=>$res_arr_value);
$jsonmsg= json_encode($msg);
echo $jsonmsg;
```

Currently i got respose like this:

```
{
    "msg": "photo exist",
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "2017-08-22": [
            {
                "image_url": "/uploads/ilse-niemann-struweg-1.jpg",
                "image_title": "Image2"
            },
            {
                "image_url": "/uploads/Teresa-Pidduck-1.jpg",
                "image_title": "Test Photo2"
            },
            {
                "image_url": "/uploads/Milagrita-Shin_Foundation.jpg",
                "image_title": "Test Photo"
            }
        ],
        "2017-04-27": [
            {
                "image_url": "/uploads/msa-youtube.png",
                "image_title": "Image"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to response like :

{ "msg": "photo exist",
 "status": "success",
 "data": 
[ { "records":
 [ { "image": "/uploads/ilse-niemann-struweg-1.jpg",
 "date":"2017-08-22", 
"title": "Image2" 
},
 { "image": "/uploads/Milagrita-Shin_Foundation.jpg",
 "date":"2017-08-22", 
"title": "Test Photo" } 
], 
"records":
 [{ "image": "/uploads/msa-youtube.png", 
"date":"2017-04-27", 
"title": "Image"} ] } ] }

Comment: what you want to achieve?

Comment: Is that the original data or the expected output? You need to give us _all_ the information. The original data, the expected output _and_ your attempt to solve it yourself. The question is currently _very_ unclear.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , this is expected result.

Comment: Please read my comment. We don't have close to enough info to be able to help you. You also need to make some attempt yourself. SO isn't a free coding service.

Comment: yes you can, but it's not clear from where you are getting your data? if it's from db then you can apply `DESC` according to date

Comment: You're json syntax is erroneous, please fix it

Comment: _Do not_ post additional data in comments. Edit _your original question_ instead. As you can see, it's pretty unreadable in comments.

Comment: The expected output is invalid. Object properties needs to be _unique_. You have multiple properties with the name `date` + the value is a string, which then have an array?!? Please read up on json structures before continuing.

Comment: So, how i got the response as datewise,becz as i had got the response is not ok.

Comment: You need to figure out what the expected output _actually_ should look like. The current format in your question is _invalid_ and _impossible_.

Comment: Again, _you_ need to figure out _how the expected output should look like_.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i found answer.As i want.

{   "msg": "photo exist",
    "status": "success",
    "data": [{
            "date": "2017-08-25",
            "records": [
                {
                    "image_url": "/uploads/for-international-students-img1.jpg",
                    "post_date": "2017-08-25",
                    "image_title": "Test3"
                },
                {
                    "image_url": "/uploads/academic-overview.jpg",
                    "post_date": "2017-08-25",
                    "image_title": "Test"
                },
                {
                    "image_url": "/uploads/source_img.jpg",
                    "post_date": "2017-08-25",
                    "image_title": "Demo Testing"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2017-08-22",
            "records": [
                {
                    "image_url": "/uploads/roselle-sherriff-img.jpg",
                    "post_date": "2017-08-22",
                    "image_title": "Testing Image2"
                },
                {
                    "image_url": "/uploads/acb_img.png",
                    "post_date": "2017-08-22",
                    "image_title": "Testing Image1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "date": "2017-04-27",
            "records": [
                {
                    "image_url": "/uploads/programmes-offered-1.jpg",
                    "post_date": "2017-04-27",
                    "image_title": "Image"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}